# C++: get simple function name instead of full qualified name

Tags: android, c++

I'd like to display function name in my log macro and I use `__func__`.

However, for a function like:

```c
int foo(int)
```

`__func__` returns `int foo(int)` instead of `foo`.

`int foo(int)` is too long. I want `foo`.

Does anyone know how to get `foo`?

Environment is Android opensource project and compiler is clang++ with -std=c++14.

Comment: How about some string manipulation?

Comment: `foo` would be ambiguous for overloaded functions. I don't think there will be a built in way to do that. Take Yunnosch's advice.

Comment: `__func__` should only give you the name. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @geza  compiler is the default compiler used by android 7.0, which is clang++ 5.0. The same code compiled by NDK is OK, only name is printed.

Comment: @Yunnosch @super  seems easy to do this.  I think I can just get string between `::` and `(`